How to get rid of the indent in the references?
In my biography, I see that the first line of a reference is slightly indented, and I want to make it aligned with with following lines (second and the following lines.) How can I do it?
Here is what it looks like currently:

Here are the codes that can generate a minimal working example:
Main file:
\documentclass[a4paper,table]{report}
\input{settings_a4.tex}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\vspace*{4em}
\cite{bolshov_tunable_2015, batchelor_introduction_2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


% bibliography %
% \usepackage[style=authoryear, 
% backend=biber, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1, giveninits=false, 
% uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, date=year]{biblatex}
% \renewbibmacro{in:}{} 

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1, giveninits=false, 
uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, date=year]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 
\addbibresource{references2.bib}

% suppress initials in the bibliography %
\DeclareNameFormat{family}{
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}

\usepackage{fouriernc}

% font issues
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone
  \usepackage[scaled=1.00]{helvet} % Helvetica clone
\else
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  %\usepackage{newcent} % Century Schoolbook font
  \setsansfont{Helvetica}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\fi

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\sffamily}
\sectionfont{\sffamily} % Use sans-serif in section-level headers
\subsectionfont{\sffamily} % Use sans-serif in section-level headers
\subsubsectionfont{\sffamily}

% change the font of contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\sffamily} 
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\sffamily} 
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\sffamily} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\sffamily}

% additional packages and configurations
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} % Customized lists
\usepackage{nicematrix} % Enhanced matrices
\usepackage{caption} % Custom captions for figures and tables
\usepackage{mathtools} % Mathematical typesetting enhancements
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} % Block arrays and struts
\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy text generator
\usepackage{nicefrac} % Typesetting fractions
\usepackage{cancel} % Cancel out parts of mathematical expressions
\usepackage{textcomp} % Additional text symbols
\usepackage{subfig} % Subfigures
\usepackage{float} % Improved interface for floating objects
\usepackage{geometry} % For adjusting page margins
\usepackage{graphicx, multicol} % Enhanced support for graphics
\usepackage{pseudocode} % Environment for specifying algorithms in a natural way
\usepackage[mmddyy]{datetime} % Uses YEAR-MONTH-DAY format for dates
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier} % Code formatting for MATLAB
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding
\usepackage[super]{nth} % Ordinal numbers with superscripts
\usepackage{booktabs} % Professional-quality tables
\usepackage{xcolor} % Color support
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % Typesetting chemical formulas
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % Required for strikethrough (\sout)
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}


%%% caption issues
\captionsetup{skip=1pt} 
\captionsetup{font=small}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER ISSUES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}

% Chapters do not start on a new page
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage}{\par}{}{}

% 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}

% 5. Reduce space between chapter titles and section titles
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{03pt}{03pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{03pt}{03pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{03pt}{03pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHAPTER ISSUES%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% additional configurations
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\centering\thepage\end{minipage}} % Centered page number
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize \textcolor{red}{#1}}} % Enables comments in red on margin
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

% adjust margins in centimeters
\geometry{
  left=2.27cm, % 0.5 inch
  right=2.27cm, % 0.5 inch
  top=0.27cm, % 0.5 inch
  bottom=1.2cm, % 0.5 inch
  columnsep=20pt, % Space between columns
}

% \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} % change font to Charter

%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt} % Add a line between columns


\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\definecolor{darkGrey}{HTML}{A2A2A2}
\newcommand{\keywordtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=darkGrey!35,fill=darkGrey!35,rounded corners=0.4ex,inner xsep=0.75ex,inner ysep =0.55ex,text height=1.3ex,text depth=0.10ex]{#1};
}


References.bib:
@book{batchelor_introduction_2010,
    location = {Cambridge},
    edition = {14. print},
    title = {An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics},
    isbn = {978-0-521-66396-0},
    series = {Cambridge mathematical library},
    pagetotal = {615},
    publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
    author = {Batchelor, G. K.},
    date = {2010},
    langid = {english},
}

@article{bolshov_tunable_2015,
    title = {Tunable diode laser spectroscopy as a technique for combustion diagnostics},
    volume = {106},
    issn = {05848547},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S058485471500021X},
    doi = {10.1016/j.sab.2015.01.010},
    pages = {45--66},
    journaltitle = {Spectrochimica Acta Part B: Atomic Spectroscopy},
    shortjournal = {Spectrochimica Acta Part B: Atomic Spectroscopy},
    author = {Bolshov, M.A. and Kuritsyn, Yu.A. and Romanovskii, Yu.V.},
    urldate = {2024-01-16},
    date = {2015-04},
    langid = {english},
}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Especially the % after \DeclareNameFormat{family}{ would be important to avoid an extra space before the family name. Whether this would be enough is hard to say, because you've added only a code snippet, but I would need a minimal working example with bibliography to be able to reproduce the problem and test my guess.

@cabohah, I added a full script that should make it possible for you to compile. I was unclear about %, tried to get rid of it, did not solve anything.

The % is still missing and please don't simply post the whole document split into several files. Try to make a MWEB as explained at the link of my second comment.

Off-topic: Your conditional loading of packages is overwritten by the later unconditional loading of fontenc. So I would recommend to clear out the document preamble and keep only those packages and declarations you really need and use, and also to load packages only once. Additionally for parskip instead of parindent I would recommend package parskip.

As explained in What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) the end of line is also a space. Therefore you have to be careful with end of lines in declarations. Here, you've an unwanted space:
\DeclareNameFormat{family}{

resulting the optical extra indent of the first line:

If I add the recommended % immediately after the { (and also reduce the example to a more minimal one):
\begin{filecontents}{references2.bib}
@book{batchelor_introduction_2010,
    location = {Cambridge},
    edition = {14. print},
    title = {An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics},
    isbn = {978-0-521-66396-0},
    series = {Cambridge mathematical library},
    pagetotal = {615},
    publisher = {Cambridge Univ. Press},
    author = {Batchelor, G. K.},
    date = {2010},
    langid = {english},
}

@article{bolshov_tunable_2015,
    title = {Tunable diode laser spectroscopy as a technique for combustion diagnostics},
    volume = {106},
    issn = {05848547},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S058485471500021X},
    doi = {10.1016/j.sab.2015.01.010},
    pages = {45--66},
    journaltitle = {Spectrochimica Acta Part B: Atomic Spectroscopy},
    shortjournal = {Spectrochimica Acta Part B: Atomic Spectroscopy},
    author = {Bolshov, M.A. and Kuritsyn, Yu.A. and Romanovskii, Yu.V.},
    urldate = {2024-01-16},
    date = {2015-04},
    langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,table]{report}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1, giveninits=false, 
uniquelist=false, uniquename=false, date=year]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 
\addbibresource{references2.bib}

% suppress initials in the bibliography %
\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}
\begin{document}
\cite{bolshov_tunable_2015, batchelor_introduction_2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

the unwanted extra space is not longer there:

So your question is a duplicate of the linked one.
